# Renaming files in a directory from a data frame

Tags: python

I have a a bunch of pdf files in a directory and I need to add a specific ID to the front of the file name. I have a csv that contains the current name mapped to the name I want to update to. I found some threads on here and tried to use the code but unfortunately I can only get the first file name to update.

The df is set up similar to below - file would be the current name and update is what I am trying to update it to.

```
file                update
aaa - bbb - 2020    1001_aaa - bbb - 2020
aaa - ccc - 2020    2212_aaa - ccc - 2020
aaa - ddd - 2020    3133_aaa - ddd - 2020
```

The code below will update the first one as expected but the loop does not continue.

```
file_path = "OneDrive/Desktop/Hello/Mapping.csv"
df= pd.read_csv(file_path)
df.head()

path = r'OneDrive\Desktop\Hello\Forms'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
#print(onlyfiles)
currentfilename= onlyfiles[0].split(".pdf")
#print(currentfilename)
for i in range(3):
#print(currentfilename,df['file'][i])
if str(currentfilename)==str(df['file'][i]):
    corrosponding_id=df['update'][i]
    print(path+"\\"+corrosponding_email)
    rename(path+"\\"+str(currentfilename)+".pdf",path+"\\"+corrosponding_id+".pdf")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also the code you've given would need the `if` statement to be indented

Comment: Please update the formatting. Right now, Python would throw an indentation error.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the dataframe and rename

```
import os

file_path = "OneDrive/Desktop/Hello/Mapping.csv"
folder = r'OneDrive/Desktop/Hello/Forms'

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

for row in df.itertuples():
    original_file_path = os.path.join(folder, row.file, '.pdf')
    new_file_path = os.path.join(folder, row.update, '.pdf')

    os.rename(original_file_path, new_file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue. You are doing currentfilename = onlyfiles[0].split(".pdf"),
which causes currentfilename to only equal the first file, but all you need to switch in your code is this: (notice the indents and changed lines)

```
file_path = "OneDrive/Desktop/Hello/Mapping.csv"
df= pd.read_csv(file_path)
df.head()

path = r'OneDrive\Desktop\Hello\Forms'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
#print(onlyfiles)
currentfilename= [file.split(".pdf") for file in onlyfiles] # CHANGED
#print(currentfilename)
for i in range(3):
   #INDENTED
   #print(currentfilename[i],df['file'][i])
   if str(currentfilename[i])==str(df['file'][i]):
       corrosponding_id=df['update'][i]
       print(path+"\\"+corrosponding_email)
    
   rename(path+"\\"+str(currentfilename[i])+".pdf",path+"\\"+corrosponding_id+".pdf")
```

Comment: Thank you for you help - I tried to run the code and am getting this error when I run the line - currentfilename= [file.split(".pdf") for file in onlyfiles[0]. "File "<ipython-input-29-8b19e23090c4>", line 18
    #rename(path+"\\"+str(currentfilename[i])+".pdf",path+"\\"+corrosponding_id+".pdf")
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

Comment: Hey @HillaryMandich -- sorry I thought I made edits to my original post (since there was a typo), but I guess they did not save. Try running the code I have in place now